# Create file, but fail if it exists, with bash

Tags: bash, shell

I need something that works on both MacOS and Linux.
If I use this:

```
touch myfile.lock; echo $?
```

it will always exit with 0.
I need a command that will fail if the file already exists. What can I use?

Comment: When the file already exists, `touch` just updates the modification time, it doesn't fail.

Comment: that is correct, I need it to fail, or give me some sign/signal that the file exists

Comment: The techniques mentioned in the duplicate reference are good, but my favourite technique is is a symlink. Doesn't have to link to a file, it can link to arbitrary text, for example check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10891984/1072112).

Comment: good idea, also since mkdir is atomic, I can honestly just use that instead of creating a file